# Using Beautiful Soup to get specific tr meta data

Tags: python, html, regex, beautifulsoup, metadata

I have a bizarre problem. I am using python to scrape a page using beautiful soup. One value I need is in the tr meta-data which I have been able to print to my screen using the following command:

```
meta = tr.findNext('td', {'class':'field1'})
attr_dict = meta.a.attrs 
print(attr_dict)
```

this produces:

```
{'href': '/client/displayEmail.asp?rid=1318441&cid=12339', 
 'rel': ['gb_page_center[940,', '600]'], 
 'title': 'ID: manualavenue100daily120141127073104:EG_CO_NEWS_1/08-14-14_yahoo\rLooking for schools? Get free information today.\rFrom: degree@newsconsul.com\rDate: 11/27/2014 7:33:34 AM'}
```

I want to extract the following information: EG_CO_NEWS_1/08-14-14_yahoo but cannot seem to get it.

Currently I'm doing this :

```
campaign_raw = str(attr_dict['title'][:80])
```

which produces:

```
'Lookianualavenue100daily120141127073104:EG_CO_NEWS_1/08-14-14_yahoo'
```

A weird concatenation of the subject and template name in an unexpected order.

I tried to split the string on a ':' and take the last segment, and that produces:
Looki_NEWS_1/08-14-14_yahoo

I have no idea what to do. I've experimented with regular expressions but that does not seem to work either. Anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Can you post your full code and link to the site you wish to scrape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unexpected order is causing by `'\r'` character or carriage return. replace it with `''`  or `' '`and then process your string.

```
str(attr_dict['title']).replace('\r', '')
```

Consider the string:

```
st = "This is SO\rThat"
```

Now if you print the string,

```
print st
That is SO
```

This happens because when a `\r` or `carriage return` is encountered the device's position is reset to the beginning of a line of text.

Comment: The string replace didn't quite work, but     new_attr_dict = re.sub(r'\r', ' ', attr_dict['title'])     nailed it. I've learned something new about carriage returns. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `\r` characters in that `title` attribute are what's causing this. `\r` is the CARRIAGE RETURN character, U+0013. The character that's normally used for the end of one line of text is the LINEFEED character, U+0010, which is `\n` in Python (and most other programming languages).

What happens when you print a `\n` character is that the cursor goes to the start of a new line. But what happens when you print a `\r` character, the cursor goes to the start of the *current* line; this is intended to be used by programs that want to keep the user informed of their progress ("0% done... 10% done... 20% done...") without getting into complicated processes to move the cursor around: just print a `\r` character, reprint the N% done message, and keep going.

And what's happening *here* is that you're taking the first 80 characters of the `title` attribute, and putting them in `campaign_raw`, which eventually (I assume) gets printed. And it just so happens that trimming 80 characters includes the first \r and a few characters from the phrase "Looking for schools?". So when you print that string, it prints the entire ID, then the `\r` makes it return to the start of the line and print the rest (a few characters from "Looking for schools?").

Replace the `\r` with the `\n` and you'll have a better idea of what's going on. I suspect you'll find some other bugs in your code in the process, but at least you'll be able to see the output properly at that point.